# How to download it without pip2

Tags: cuckoo

I tried to download the cuckoo on windows, While I got the error 'pip2 install -U cuckoo'.
The default version of pip on my windows system is for python3.

I tried to download python27, and went to the folder, try to pip install. I still failed

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Try using simply ```pip install cuckoo```

Comment: the default pip version is 3. You can download cuckoo with python3 environment.

Comment: I have solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little trick.

First, you do need to download the python27 and go to the python27 directory.

Then, you need to download pip2 (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py), use this command: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

Then python.exe get-pip.py

Now, it still does not work if you just type pip2 install ..
You should use python.exe -m pip install -U cuckoo. (download package under the version of this directory).

Answer (score 0):

After you download the WSL for ubuntu 16.04. You will meet an error the next time you reboot your PC. It is like registerDistribution error. You just need to uninstall all anti-virus software. For me, it is the McAfee. After you uninstall it, reboot your pc. You will find it works normally.

The reference is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLGJHgv6uWA.